# C++ compiler: inline usage of a non-inline function defined in the same module

Tags: c++, inline, compiler-optimization

**T.hpp**

```
class T
{
    int _i;

public:
    int get() const;
    int some_fun();
};
```

**T.cpp**

```
#include "T.hpp"

int T::get() const
{ return _i; }

int T::some_fun()
{
    // noise
    int i = get(); // (1)
    // noise
}
```

`get()` is a non-inline function, however, it's defined in the same module as `some_fun`. Since the compiler can see the definition of `get` in the context of `some_fun`, do compilers, in optimized builds at least, apply the optimization of replacing `get()` by just `_i` in line `(1)`?

If I'm not wrong, I think that, with the exception of templates, the compiler only does a one-pass parsing. What if `get` is defined after `some_fun`?

Comment: What if? What happens when you try it?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don't speak assembly so I don't know how could I positively know if inlining have been applied or not.

Comment: you dont need to understand all details to see if there is a difference. Btw "inline" is a rather overloaded term. The C++ terminology for "inline" has diverged from the traditional meaning of "calls to the function are inlined". When you say "`get()` is a non-line function" then this is correct in C++ terms, nevertheless the compiler might inline calls to the function

Comment: I think it will not be inlined, because it has external linkage. T.cpp is single compilation unit, which creates some object file T.o after compilation stage - if any other module will access it, it will be linked by T::get object address

Comment: You will have to enable link time optimization (LTO) for the compiler to be able to automatically inline this (e.g. read [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) ). This will slow down linking by a bit though.

Comment: @JHBonarius I'm not talking about inlining the function, but doing an inline substitution from a specific call point. I'm aware about LTO but it usually takes too long to compile, so I never really used it. Anyway, I have already an answer, read below, where an inline substitution takes place without inlining the function itself.

Comment: Your answer describes a different situation, where all objects are defined in one entity. In the situation you describe in the question, when including the header in another file,  the compiler cannot see the implemention, thus cannot optimize the function call away. Link time optimization can. Apples and oranges

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I answered myself. I thought I didn't speak assembly but it wasn't that hard to try.

Code:

```
class T
{
    int _i = 5;

public:
    int get() const;
    int some_fun();
};

int T::get() const { return _i; }

int T::some_fun()
{
    int i = get();
    return i;
}

int main()
{
    T o;
    return o.some_fun();
}
```

Non-optimized assembly output (using godbolt.org). A lot of stuff but you can see the explicit `call`s:

```
T::get() const:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        pop     rbp
        ret
T::some_fun():
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::get() const              // !!!!
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], eax
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        leave
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
        lea     rax, [rbp-4]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::some_fun()          // !!!!
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

Optimized output (`-O3`):

```
T::get() const:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
T::some_fun():
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
main:
        mov     eax, 5
        ret
```

Here, `some_fun` has inlined the call to `get` (the `call` instruction has been removed and its definition is the same as `get` now), but the `get` function is still defined.

`main` went even further by doing an inline substitution of the call to `some_fun` and then realizing that `o` hasn't changed and at that point it still retains its default value of `5`, so `main` directly returns `5` without even creating `o`.